# BigQuery - convert String to Timestamp with default value

Tags: google-bigquery, timestamp

In the BigQuery I have `String` column which contains timestamp data. In the query I want to convert it to the `Timestamp` column.
I know, that BigQuery have `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP` functions. Issue is, that this data comes from the external source, so I need to be ready for the possibility, that input `String` may not be correct timestamp.
While using these functions inside the query it will fail, if input data is in the wrong format.
Is there a method to let this query pass even with wrong input data? For example, to change not correct format to `null` or some arbitrary timestamp like `1900-01-01 00:00:00`.
Simple regexp check will not be sufficient. For example `2020-02-29 00:00:00` is a completely fine timestamp, but `2019-02-29 00:00:00` is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix with SAFE in order to get NULLs for invalid data.

```
SELECT safe.timestamp('2019-02-29 00:00:00') as tt
```

returns

```
[
  {
    "tt": null
  }
]
```

> If you begin a function with the SAFE. prefix, it will return NULL
>   instead of an error. The SAFE. prefix only prevents errors from the
>   prefixed function itself: it does not prevent errors that occur while
>   evaluating argument expressions. The SAFE. prefix only prevents errors
>   that occur because of the value of the function inputs, such as "value
>   out of range" errors; other errors, such as internal or system errors,
>   may still occur. If the function does not return an error, SAFE. has
>   no effect on the output. If the function never returns an error, like
>   RAND, then SAFE. has no effect.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_prefix